# How to add more parameters while predicting using LSTM

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, lstm

What changes should I make in this code to predict the output based on all the parameters listed on the dataset and predict the next day opening stock price?

When I tried to run it showed an out of shape error. This code works fine with only 1 parameter.

My code is as follows:

```
dataset_train = pd.read_csv('ongc_train.csv')  
dataset_train = dataset_train.dropna()  
training_set = dataset_train.iloc[:, 1:2].value

# Creating a dataset with 60 timesteps and 1 output
X_train = []    
Y_train = []    
for i in range(60,2493):    
    X_train.append(training_set_scaled[i-60:i, 0])    
    Y_train.append(training_set_scaled[i, 0])       
X_train, Y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(Y_train)         

# Reshaping
X_train  np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))

# Fitting the RNN to the training set
regressor.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=32)

# Getting the predicted stock price of 2017
# Concatenating the original training and test set
# Vertical concatenating of open stock prices
dataset_total = pd.concat((dataset_train['Open'], dataset_test['Open']), axis=0)
inputs = dataset_total[len(dataset_total) - len(dataset_test) - 60:].values
inputs = inputs.reshape(-1, 1)
inputs = sc.transform(inputs)
X_test = []
for i in range(60, 61):
    X_test.append(inputs[i-60:i, 0])
X_test=np.array(X_test)   
X_test=np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1))
predicted_stock_price = regressor.predict(X_test)
predicted_stock_price = sc.inverse_transform(predicted_stock_price)
actual = dataset_test.iloc[:, 1:2].values
print("Predicted Stock Price:",predicted_stock_price)
```

Thank you.